# Datetime parse exception in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have tried all the ways, however not sure why the string date is not getting converted to datetime.

```
string windowsTime = "2/21/2009 10:35:14 PM"
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(windowsTime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);
```

I used, DateTime.Parse, ParseExact, Convert.ToDatetime.
But nothing is working, I am getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

can somebody advise what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as specified in the MSDN

> "MM" The month, from 01 through 12. More information: The "MM" Custom
>   Format Specifier.

[Custom Datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I know MM is the month, but what I am doing here?

Comment: @mmssaann 2/21/2009 -> the 2 is not MM format as you specified. it should be 02

Comment: In simple terms, *MM* expects two digits. No more, no less.

Answer (score 2):

Since the month has only one digit this is correct `M`. 
You also have to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`(means current-culture). Otherwise all `/` will be replaced with the actual date separator of your current culture( for me `de-DE` it's `.`):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(windowsTime, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Custom date and time format strings: the "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)